# How to extend Bootstrap color classes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, colors

I am using Bootstrap 3.3.0 on my site.

The one thing I run into is that their contextual classes of `primary`, `info`, `success`, `warning` and `danger` can be limiting.

For instance, I have an app that is going to require several other colors such as purple, yellow and possibly some hues in between `primary` and `info`.

Now, before I start rolling my own color-wheel .css file, I would like to know if there is already and known Bootstrap *extension* on contextual classes.

Then this would integrate into the existing color scheme just perfectly.

Thank you!

**EDIT**

So far nobody has answered this post...

Well, for those that want to help not only myself but many others who have gone ***"Jeez... I really wish I had a 'yellow' color or a 'brown' color or a 'purple' color..."*** when using Bootstrap, I invite any color-savvy person to scientifically come up with an extension that would extend these color classes.

It shouldn't be that difficult - but there is a science to color-codification (of which I am not particularly trained in) and if it is to be a proper extension, then it should be done per these standards so that others may use it too.

Comment: You can customise the colors in [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#colors)..but it will replace the existing color of primary or info classes

Comment: Don't know any ready-made css extension. But you can make use of the following to chose the customized theme colors: https://color.adobe.com/

Also I think this is going to be useful

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: Well, I am not color-savvy - so if somebody can create a color extension .css file that would be very helpful not only to me, but many others I am sure

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I think Bootstrap provide us five contextual colors by default and it will never be enough for every website since each of them has different design lead to the different color scheme. What I can suggest you is to.

1. Visit http://clrs.cc/ to see some color might be useful.
2. Learn SCSS and the way it controls the color by using lighten and darken, or mix. Meaning you define some default popular colors and use these function to utilize it without define a lot of new colors. Check this [article](http://jackiebalzer.com/color)

Comment: Thanks @trungk18 - very helpful. the clrs.cc so far has been great. Going to mess around with this for a bit. Waiting for a couple other replies - but so far this is the most helpful.

Comment: Welcome, hope you can find your expected answer soon :D

Answer (score 4):

I think **there is no good answer** to your question.
Not with the current or the next available version (v4).
Those particular conditional classes are implemented in various components, like tables, form controls, buttons, cards, tags, progress bars, list group items, links and texts.
These components may have quite a few modifier rules for each existing conditional class, eg for `.btn-danger`

```css
.btn-danger:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #c9302c;
  border-color: #c12e2a;
}
.btn-danger:focus,
.btn-danger.focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #c9302c;
  border-color: #c12e2a;
}
.btn-danger:active,
.btn-danger.active,
.open > .btn-danger.dropdown-toggle {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #c9302c;
  border-color: #c12e2a;
  background-image: none;
}
.btn-danger:active:hover,
.btn-danger:active:focus,
.btn-danger:active.focus,
.btn-danger.active:hover,
.btn-danger.active:focus,
.btn-danger.active.focus,
.open > .btn-danger.dropdown-toggle:hover,
.open > .btn-danger.dropdown-toggle:focus,
.open > .btn-danger.dropdown-toggle.focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ac2925;
  border-color: #8b211e;
}
.btn-danger.disabled:focus,
.btn-danger.disabled.focus,
.btn-danger:disabled:focus,
.btn-danger:disabled.focus {
  background-color: #d9534f;
  border-color: #d9534f;
}
.btn-danger.disabled:hover,
.btn-danger:disabled:hover {
  background-color: #d9534f;
  border-color: #d9534f;
}
```

If you look at the source code you will notice that, again the example of the buttons, the authors are using mixins to generate the rules for the conditional classes:

```css
//
// Alternate buttons
//

.btn-danger {
  @include button-variant($btn-danger-color, $btn-danger-bg, $btn-danger-border);
}
```

and somewhere else

```css
$btn-danger-color:               #fff !default;
$btn-danger-bg:                  $brand-danger !default;
$btn-danger-border:              $btn-danger-bg !default;
```

and again, somewhere else

```css
$brand-danger:              #d9534f !default;
```

The rules are hardcoded in the source files so the only way to achieve something here is to extend those files with new rules and add new colors, **basically modifying bootstrap and recompile it**.
This is doable but consider this:

- You need to maintain the code (future updates can be incompatible with your overrides)
- You need extra tools and skills, at least how to work with sass and how to do your own version of bootstrap
- You need to implement this extra conditional classes in many .sass files
- Having a 'purple color' like you say would mean having a 3-4 color palette that you need to test for each component.

There is also a nomenclature issue: .btn-warning, .text-danger, .table-info etc have a semantic meaning while you propose color names.

I don't see a very good extension coming out of it.
Who defines the palette for each additional conditional class?  These rules have weight even in terms of bytes, you don't want to have so many conditional class to cover most of the users.

Instead you may want a generator of rules for each conditional class you decide to add. A tool like this can be made but again, should be maintained and also retro-compatible. For example there are 7 version to cover more updated than yours (3.3.0, still in LESS) plus the new v4 (SASS) Is it worth it?
Generally those conditional classes are enough for most uses and if you want you can [generate customized versions of bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) with different color combinations.

Answer (score 1):

To reach this easily i'll tell you what i made.
I created my own css library that i load after bootstrap's one.
**How to do it properly?**
On there, for example (let's style our own bootstrap's btn-* classes) you must copy one of the the btn-* class. 
Then add the word that you want. FE:

```
.btn-earth{/*same as bootstrap but changing the following */ background-color: brown; color: white; font-wheigt: bold; border:none;}
.btn-sun{/*same as bootstrap but changing the following */ background-color: yellow; color: black; border:1px solid orange;}
```

**But, if you need to override something:**
As the bootstrap classes sometimes have accurated selectors, you'll have to copy the same selector in order to overlay a bootstrap class. Use !important if youn need (but not recommended because you may want to edit some in a particular case) So, if bootstrap has a 3 accuracy level selector, must use the same (as your library will load after bootstrap, it will take priority **ONLY** if you load bootstrap's css from local and not by CDN, in that case, you will need to create more accurated selectors than bootstrap's have) F.E:

```
/* bootstrap selector: */
.navbar > li > a {/* whatever */}
/* if you load bootstrap by CDN you must create an accurated one as follows: */
.container > .navbar > li > a {/* whatever */}
/* you'll have to remember that you have to set the navbar inside a container to make it sense */
```

If i have some extra time (after my 11 daily hours of working in front of a PC) i'll compile a css library to reach this job and provide some documentation.
I'm sure there have to be a library somewhere on the net, but it's a mostly personal thing, so if you use a purple button, it may not be the shade of purple that you wanted...

Hope it helps! you can do it quick, writting your own css library line-by-line when you need it, after a pair of projects you'll have an extense one. =)

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks and yes, I am well aware that I can compile my own library and can do that if necessary. I am trying to get a full Bootstrap color class extension - which I think many people can benefit from. So if you can put something together you might just be writing a piece of history

Comment: Then we must apply a comprehensive and natural nomenclature. You can text me and share some classes to work with bootstrap. Text me on telegram @joelbonetr

Comment: Hi @joel, thanks for your comm on this. I prefer to keep it on here vs Telegram (plus I rarely use those systems).

For the purpose of this extension, I do believe the `bg-purple` would be fine or `bg-yellow` for example.

We could do somethin like `bg-prince` or `bg-banana`, but it would entirely be up to you.

Looking forward to whatever you put together

Comment: here it's one of my personal libraries extended with color btn classes (i usually don't keep color modifications cause i write it when i need, but here's a sample and many other classes that can be usefull.)

https://mega.nz/#!R591AJ6L!T0gT8bFEl5WeqAHuSXCLb6AzGlkS9qI4s4Uu4t9TTiE

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this css extension of BS 4 that I created. It may help you, and feel free to add more colors!

[BootstrapColorsExtended](https://github.com/robert1233/BootstrapColorsExtended)

Right now, including BS4's colors, there are a total of 21 colors, spanning most of the color wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Two potential ways to accomplish this within Less.js (which has native extension functionality):

http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature-extend-syntax

Mixins are a slightly different approach - you can create a reusable piece of CSS that can be called within other Less blocks.

https://www.sitepoint.com/less-beyond-basics-bootstrap-mixins-library/

Either of those should be sufficient to accomplish the desired task.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library @ http://www.colorstrap.com/, which has bootstrap contextual classes for all the default HTML colors.

This is what I have found that has been the most useful and ready-made.

Some of the colors are ugly - but you have many to choose from.

Have at it!